# Gradle can't find play services after update android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated my android studio this morning and updated my whole android sdk. Including the extra's like play services and etc...

I always get:

```
Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52.
Required by:
    ar-android:Ar:unspecified
<a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>
```

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Hi..I've the same issue, have you had any success?

Comment: You need to set the lib in the build.gralde.

Comment: I have that done I think like this:  
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.2.jar')
    compile project(':ws_wrapper')
    compile project(':custom_slider_library')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
}

Comment: is this what you meant?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it downloading a package from the Android SDK mananger.

Open the SDK Manager (from Eclipse or Android or the standalone version) and select the package 'Google Play Services'.